# Cmake Library With Qt Object?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make a shared library that my other Qt projects can use. In the library I have a class that looks similar to this:

```
A.h

class A : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    A(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~A();

protected:
    void overriddenQtFunc() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE; // Overriding a QtWidget function.

    // other variables and functions here...

}

A.cpp
A::A(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent){}
A::~A(){}
void A::overriddenQtFunc(){  // Custom implementation here...  }
// Other function implementations.
```

My Cmake for the library looks as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
set(LIB_NAME "TestLib")

find_package(QT5Widgets)

include_directories("includes") # Where my A.h file lives along with
                                # my other custom library code.

set(SRCS # Source list here)
set(HDRS # Header list here)

add_library(${LIB_NAME} ${SRCS} ${HDRS})

target_include_directories(${LIB_NAME} PRIVATE ${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_include_directories(${LIB_NAME} PUBLIC "includes")
```

Everything compiles and works ok when I take "Q_OBJECT" out of the class along with my overridden method. Otherwise when I want to compile with them, I get

```
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall A::overriddenQtFunc(void)"
```

Is there something else I need to do to get it to link properly? Does it have something to do with my sources not being "moc"ed?

Comment: In `A.cpp` you have: `void overriddenQtFunc(){` Shouldn't that be: `void A::overriddenQtFunc(){` so you are not defining a free function that has no relation to class `A`? Or is your example wrong?

Comment: right you are @drescherjm. Edit made.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
```

Comment: I also tried with CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR and CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR